# How to make a tab bar application which i can use to view display my google map on a button click.-android

Tags: android

I am creating a tourist attraction app.i have already created my tab bar application with 3 tabs and a few button links.I am currently researching on how to display my google map on one of my button clicks in my tab application bar.I would like to know how do i implement the google map into one of those button.I have posted what i have done here http://www.mediafire.com/?bdgdssdi6rs9oab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Intent` to call a built-in google map application. Therefore in the `Button` `OnClickListener` write the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                      Uri.parse("geo:37.827500, -122.481670"));
startActivity(i);
```

Note that in order to display the Maps application, you also need to run application on an AVD that supports the Google API's

Comment: So i would need to create a new project that have a google api+android,i tried making a new project but why doesnt it work the button in bakuteh.xml doesnt work it crash after i click it which should link me to my created google map, i also uploaded ithttp://www.mediafire.com/?zi4a534rmd246dm. by the way i am doing it on android 2.1.It work but why didnt my work because i would need to design a google map that can track my current positon and given from my database it will extracts for example 3 closet place where it sells good pizza

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to create a new project. Just go to Window --> AVD Manager -- > new. Create a new AVD (Android Virtual Device). Make sure that you chose Google API as a target. Then run your application using this AVD.

Comment: ok then how do i start a database which i can extract information and display it on my google map with the given address from the database